# How to execute js function after Get request? W/ Twit

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I am using Twit, a Twitter API Client. And I was wondering how I can execute a function after the get request?

Currently the getUsers() function is executing after the printUsers() function, but I execute the getUsers() function then printUsers() function.

```js
console.log("Hello Bot");

var Twit = require('twit');

var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);

var randomUsers = [];

function getUsers() {
    //  search twitter for all tweets containing the word 'javascript'
    var params = {
        user_id: '3180043436',
        count: 2
    }

    T.get('friends/ids', params, gotFriends);
    T.get('followers/ids', params, gotFollowers);

    function gotFriends(err, data, response) {
        console.log(data.ids);
        Array.prototype.push.apply(randomUsers, data.ids);
    };

    function gotFollowers(err, data, response) {
        console.log(data.ids);
        Array.prototype.push.apply(randomUsers, data.ids);
    };
    console.log();
}

function printUsers(){
 console.log(randomUsers);
}

getUsers();
printUsers();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) has promise support. so if you don't pass it a callback it will return a promise. You could collect these promises and run all of them in parallel using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) or [async.parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) library methods and at last run a callback function on prepaired data:

```
console.log("Hello Bot");

var Twit = require('twit');
var $ = require('jquery');

var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);

var randomUsers = [];

function getUsers(callback) {
    //  search twitter for all tweets containing the word 'javascript'
    var params = {
        user_id: '3180043436',
        count: 2
    };

    var promise1 = T.get('friends/ids', params);
    var promise2 = T.get('followers/ids', params);

    $.when(promise1, promise2).done(function(data1, data2) {
      randomUsers.push(data1.data.ids).push(data2.data.ids);
      callback(randomUsers);
    });
}

function printUsers(randomUsers){
    console.log(randomUsers);
}

getUsers(printUsers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use callback functionality

```
$(function(){
     $.ajax(
        {
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "jsonp",
           url: "http://example.com/json.php?callback=callNow",
        } );
 });
    function callNow(data){ 
          alert(data.name + " " + data.lastname); 
    }
```

notice callNow in url and it is also the function name